# verifying unique app purchase

Tags: unique, verify

I am looking for a way to verify if my app was downloaded by a user. I want to allow users to notify me of their purchase if they intend to donate to a cause and we would donate a percentage after verification of app purchase. I would want to see/validate a proof of purchase. It has to be unique per app download.

Comment: Have the user commit his ordernumber and customernumber. That can be verified by your sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a logged in user, you can generate some unique code on every dowload ( it might be even a GUID) and supply it to the user. Then he/she must enter this code on purchase.

Comment: Hi Teddy,

Thanks for your response. Can you elaborate a bit more please on what you mean by generate at 'download' and enter on 'purchase'. Any example will be great.

mb

Comment: Hi. As you say the users can donwload your application, so it available on the internet. So there should be a button for the download and you can handle its click event. In the code to handle this you can generate the unique identifier. Then you can show this to the user on the screen, or you can send it via email.(A lot of places require email address in order to download something). About the purchase, how does the users donate? is it on the internet, bank transfer or something else.